# Is it possible to draw image using QGraphicsView from a 2D BYTE array Qt?

Tags: qt, qt4

I have a 2D BYTE (unsigned char) array. buf[50][100] which is having some data. I need to draw this buffer to an image in Qt using QGraphicsView. The byte in (x,y) represents the (x,y)th pixel of the array. How to pass this array to the QGraphicsView to draw very fast? Or is there any other method (without using QGraphicsView) to draw the image in 2D array Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `QImage` object [from a pre-existing memory area](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html#QImage-5) and then you can use a [`drawImage`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#drawImage-3) call to draw it on a normal `QPainter`.

Being your image 8 bit per pixel you will need to also [set up a palette](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html#setColor) for the image.

The palette is simply a mapping from a byte index to a QRgb color value. You can set it up like so:

```
static void setGrayColorMap(QImage * img)
{
   img->setColorCount(256);
   for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
      img->setColor(i, qRgb(i,i,i));
   }
}
```

Comment: How can I set the palette of the image? Each pixel corresponds to each byte in the array